# Error thrown when trying to execute command

Tags: java, ssh

I am having a bit of a problem trying to test for connection in using the Ganymed library in java, 2 weeks ago it was working fine with no problems but now I am getting the following error message:

```
The execute request failed.
```

Which has to do with the Ganymed "execCommand()" method. When I use WinSCP to connect, everything works but trying to connect using java gives me the error. I am also thinking if maybe firewalls can be the cause as well, just a thought.

The code I am using to execute a tail command is the following:

```
      import java.io.BufferedReader;
      import java.io.IOException;
      import java.io.InputStream;
      import java.io.InputStreamReader;
      import java.util.HashMap;
      import java.util.Map;
      import ch.ethz.ssh2.Connection;
      import ch.ethz.ssh2.Session;
      import ch.ethz.ssh2.StreamGobbler;


     public class SSHTesting {


public static void main(String[] args) {


    try{ Connection conn = new Connection("eappdev101.momentum.co.za");

    conn.connect();

        boolean isAuthenticated = conn.authenticateWithPassword("username", "password");

        if (isAuthenticated == false) {
            System.out.println("Credentials are wrong.");
        }

        Session sess = conn.openSession();

        sess.execCommand("tail -f /logs/SystemOut.log");
        InputStream stdout = new StreamGobbler(sess.getStdout());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));

        sess.close();
        conn.close();
        System.out.println("Done");
}

catch(Exception ie){
    System.out.println(ie.getMessage());
}



}

    }
```

Any shed of light is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: the code looks fine, so it could be because of SSH Server authentication configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for me it works fine with key , and i assume that you should use key for security reasons

check below code

```
private void init() throws IOException{
        char privateKeyChar[] = sshPrivateKey.toCharArray();

        conn = new Connection(ftpHostname,22);
        conn.connect();

        boolean isAuthenticated = conn.authenticateWithPublicKey(sshUsername, privateKeyChar, null);
        if (isAuthenticated == false)
            throw new IOException("Authentication failed.");

        session = conn.openSession();       
    }

    public String excuteCMD(String cmd) throws IOException
    {
        session = conn.openSession();
        session.execCommand(cmd);
        InputStream stdout = new StreamGobbler(session.getStdout());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));

        while (true)
        {

            String line = br.readLine();
            if (line == null)
                break;
            else
                output+=line;
        }

        return output;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Saddam, thank you for the quick reply, if I may ask, the sshPrivateKey is still the passowrd that I use to login or its supposed to be generated by using Putty or ? thank you.

Comment: You generate it using ssh-keygen, and put the public key under authorized_keys in Linux/Unix machines, refer to below example http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/articles/key-setup.html

Comment: Thanks for the link Saddam, I shall update you is to how I am progressing, currently checking out the link you suggested.

Comment: Hi Saddam, I found out the reason why it wasn't working was due to the server being down, and apperently someone fiddled with the credentials we use, hence the problem I was experiencing so they working on fixing the problem and all should be working again. And thanks once again for your time.